# Issue importing data into MYSQL using python (error code: "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement)

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to grab data from an API and then create a table and insert the pulled data based on the input of a cashier's name. I am interfacing with MYSQL.

data1 is a list of dictionaries in the form of:
{'cashier': [{'open': 123, 'high': 3232, 'low': 321, 'close': 117.28, 'volume': 1231232, 'datetime': 16031231612300}, {'open': 123, 'high': 3232, 'low': 321, 'close': 117.28, 'volume': 1231232, 'datetime': 16031231612300},...etc.]

I can create the table with the proper cashier name input, however, I cannot seem to insert the data shown in the data1 format shown above. I get the error ""Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement". am I doing this right with thinking that executemany() is the proper way to go for this?

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
data1 = content1.json()
cashier = input("cashier name: ")

import json
import mysql.connector

host = 'localhost' 
user = 'user'
password = 'password'  
database = 'stock_database'
        
cnxn = mysql.connector.connect(host = host, 
                                user = user, 
                                password = password, 
                                database = database)

mycursor = cnxn.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE {cashier_name}_database \
                                            (symbol_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\
                                             datetime BIGINT,\
                                             close DECIMAL,\
                                             volume DECIMAL,\
                                             high DECIMAL,\
                                             low DECIMAL, \
                                             open DECIMAL)".format(cashier_name=cashier))
```

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO {cashier_name}_database \
                                (datetime, \
                                 close, \
                                 volume, \
                                 high, \
                                 low, \
                                 open) \
                                 VALUES (%(datetime)s, %(close)s, %(volume)s, %(high)s, %(low)s, %(open)s)".format(cashier_name=cashier)

mycursor.executemany(insert_query, data1)

cnxn.commit()

mycursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your data1 is not a list of dictionaries, but dictionary with 'cashier' key and list of dictionaries as value. You can call executemany function this way:

```
mycursor.executemany(insert_query, data1['cashier'])
```

or if your data1 store values for different cashiers and you assign to cashier variable a specified value, you can use executemany function this way:

```
cashier = input("cashier name: ")
mycursor.executemany(insert_query, data1[cashier])
```

Comment: @doc_holiday, glad to help! If answer to the question was usefull for you, please approve answer to help other SO visitors to identify correct problem solving.